# issue with mixing Objective C and C++ in single file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, xcode4.2

I am having .mm file, in which i have some c++ function and few line of objective c.

For ex.

```
void display()
{
....
....
}

void doSomthing()
{
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
[button addTarget:??? action:@selector(display) ....]

[rooView addSubView:UIButton];
}
```

I am not getting the way how i could call display function which defined in same mm file?
what will be my addTarget? (self/this not working in my case )

Comment: the target is the object that will receive the `display` message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an Objective-C class and some methods to wrap your C++ function calls.

```
@interface WrapperClass : NSObject

-(void) display;

@end

void display()
{
....
....
}

@implementation WrapperClass

-(void) display
{
    display();
}

@end

static WrapperClass* wrapperObj = nil;

void doSomthing()
{
    if (wrapperObj == nil)
    {
        wrapperObj = [[WrapperClass alloc] init];
    }

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50)];
    [button addTarget: wrapperObj action:@selector(display) forControlEvents: whatever];
    [rooView addSubView:UIButton];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You cannot use `@selector()` to reference a function, you can only use it to reference an objective-c method.

Further the `UIButton` class is not capable of performing a function call when it is clicked. It can only perform an objective-c method.

You can however, "wrap" an objective-c method around the function:

```
- (void)display:(id)sender
{
    display();
}
```

Allowing this:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(display:) ....];
```

But if you are writing your own display() function, then you may as well just put it's contents in the display method.

Comment: if i ddeclare objective c function in mm file, for ex

-(void) display
{
 
}

it shows below error 
"missing context for method declaration"

Comment: @chetan:  You also need an Objective-C class to send the display message too.  You would define that in your .mm file.